# Cannot boot into Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd

This morning when I turned on my laptop (Acer Aspire s7 - 392) it came up with an error saying there is no bootable device. I've went into BIOS but all the settings seem to be alright, fear struck as I have thought that the ssd is toast. I have then run seagate's dos tool that said no errors on the disk were found and also checked it with easeUS's winPE tool that came back with the same result.

Instead of trying to reinstall windows, it was decided  that it's about time to transition to ubuntu. Installation had finished without any errors whatsoever. restarted, same error. No bootable device.

I am now writing this from the trial ubuntu installation from the usb and the ssd is listed in files and i can also see that all the OS files are on it. The previous OS on this laptop was windows 8, the only thing I did do last night was install android studio.

I have tried legacy boot, disabling secure boot and changing ATA settings in the BIOS. I am kind of at a loss what else to try here.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bootloader of your system is corrupted. A fresh Ubuntu installation should reinstall it, but somehow it didn't happened.

Boot the system using live disk of Ubuntu, `chroot` into Ubuntu installation root directory and reinstall `grub2` bootloader. For further instruction regarding the procedure of `grub2` installation several online documents are available.

Now reboot your system and make sure your hard disk as first bootable device.